# Getting posts (feeds) from Facebook, Twitter, Youtube, Google+, Instagram using their APIs

Tags: facebook, twitter, youtube-api, google-plus, instagram-api

Can I get posts with likes and other information from public profile of any user at Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Youtube and Instagram using their APIs, if I'm not logged in at any of these services? I need to use it developing PHP/JavaScript application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. But there is one condition, the profile you're accessing must be public. Also one has his own API's so it can get a little tricky. I think you don't even need PHP because the APIs from google & facebook come in JS.
A tip that might help you. [Try firebase](https://firebase.google.com). Firebase is a framework that makes client-side development easier. You can include Google APIs & facebook APIs.
I'm a native Spanish speaker so I'm sorry for my English. Anyway, check firebase. It should help.

Comment: Muchos grazias Hector! What if we will use Yii2 + jQuery (or Angular)?

Comment: Muchas gracias xD. That must not be a problem. jQuery and AngularJS are just libraries made on JS that make development easier. They are just a set of functions that you could use or not.